# What would be the ideal translation for the word "broadcaster" in Portuguese?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

To make it more clear, this broadcaster is not someone speaking over a microphone, it's just someone using their cellphone to broadcast a live session to viewers. Ideas?

Answer (score 5):

A broadcaster is generally someone, or something, that **distributes**, **relays**, **transmits** a message to someone, or something, else.

The translation provided by Google Translator for "broadcaster" is "locutor de rádio", which is a very specific type of broadcasting, for radio.

However, you can find more meaningful translations for "broadcast" such as **"transmissão"** (transmission, to transmit) or **"difundir"** (to propagate).

So the broadcaster is the **"transmissor"** or **"emissor"** as @Jacinto suggested.

Both "broadcast" and "broadcasting" can also be used as foreign words, [they are even accepted without the use of quotation marks](https://www12.senado.leg.br/manualdecomunicacao/redacao-e-estilo/estilo/estrangeirismos-grafados-sem-italico). This usually happens when foreign words are adopted as is to another language, due to relatively high usage.

Comment: Pensaste em *emissor*? Não sei porquê, soa-me melhor.

Comment: @Jacinto Parece ser uma boa escolha também.

Comment: Pá, inclui. Isto assim em abstrato é um bocado difícil: as palavras em frases tomam sentidos mais precisos. Mas de maneira geral, vejo uma pessoa mais como emissor do que transmissor; transmissor faz-me lembrar mais equipamento.

Comment: @Jacinto Mas eu editei a resposta, depois de fazer o comentário xD

Comment: Não tinha visto :)

Comment: Okay guys, for instance. You want to add a comment on a post: "The broadcaster has left the session". We would then consider "O transmissor saiu da sessão or deixou a sessão"?

Comment: @Hugo I prefer saiu

Comment: emissora é quem produz o que vai ser transmitido, transmissor é o aparato tecnológico para transmitir

Comment: @Hugo That specific sentence I would translate as "O participante saiu da sessão" (for a Brazilian audience).

Comment: @bfavaretto, even though he is not a participant? In this case remember, he is the broadcaster meaning, everyone is watching him or her, so when he leaves, the session ends and everyone drops off the broadcast. I think his role would be a bit beyond a participant. Forgot to elaborate a bit on that.

Comment: @Hugo I would prefer the "encerrou" (turned off). When a broadcaster stops his stream, nobody else will be able to see it. Using the term "saiu" or "deixou" (left) may confuse the users thinking that he left, but the stream is yet active. When i'm watching to a live stream, the message of "the broadcaster has left" is like to me: the left room, but soon will came back. When I see the message: "the broadecaster has turned off the transmission" then I know that he will not came too soon

Answer (score 0):

I would use "divulgador". The verb "divulgar" means to spread information or ideas to a large public, in any form, verbal, written or visual. "Difundir" can also be used, but the derivated noun "difusor" can be confused with something that difuses a substance in another one. "Divulgador" leaves no doubt.